# "Precisamente" versus "appunto"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, adverbs

Questi due avverbi, "precisamente" e "appunto", mi sono sempre sembrati molto simili. Potreste spiegarmi le differenze di uso tra questi due vocaboli? Per esempio, potrei scrivere queste frasi:

> - In Spagna ci sono state molte proteste contro la nuova legge sulla sicurezza cittadina, ma questa legge cerca ***precisamente*** di farla finita con le proteste dei movimenti sociali.
> - In Spagna ci sono state molte proteste contro la nuova legge sulla sicurezza cittadina, ma questa legge cerca ***appunto*** di farla finita con le proteste dei movimenti sociali.

Quale sarebbe la forma corretta?

Comment: "acabar con" in italiano ha diverse traduzioni, a seconda del contesto. "Farla finita con", "sopprimere" e "stroncare" sono alcune possibilità che potrebbero essere adatte in questo esempio.

Comment: Grazie, @karoshi! Adesso faccio la correzione nel mio post.

Comment: Tutti e due gli avverbi hanno senso in quel contesto, e forse “proprio” è ancor più idiomatico.

Answer (score 3):

Da dove stai traducendo (se stai traducendo)? Tutte e due le frasi suonano strane e secondo me ci potrebbe stare un rimaneggiamento in italiano.

Ad esempio qualcosa come:

*In Spagna ci sono state molte proteste contro la nuova legge sulla sicurezza cittadina, legge che cerca appunto di porre fine alle proteste dei movimenti sociali.*

O meglio ancora per non ripetere "proteste":

*In Spagna ci sono state molte proteste contro la nuova legge sulla sicurezza cittadina, legge che cerca appunto di porre fine a quelle da parte dei movimenti sociali.*

Se però vuoi proprio mantenere il "ma" (che suona stranissimo e forse anche sbagliato se questa frase viene lasciata da sola) probabilmente la migliore delle due è quella con "appunto".

"Precisamente" in questo genere di frasi non viene molto usato. Esempi di frasi con "precisamente":

- *Un cavallo (più precisamente quello di Maria) non voleva essere pulito*
- *Ora ti dirò precisamente cosa ho visto*

È poco usato, spesso al suo posto si usa "esattamente".

Comment: Ciao, @Davide! Non sto traducendo. Ho cercato di scrivere una frase io stessa ma, non essendo italiana, non sempre riesco a scrivere correttamente in italiano. Dunque, grazie mille del tuo suggerimento per migliorare la frase!

Comment: @davide.azzini: secondo me il "ma" ci può stare. Credo che Charo volesse dire una cosa simile a: "ci sono state molte proteste...., ma sono proprio le proteste ciò che questa legge vuole [sopprimere|rendere illegali|etc.]".

Comment: @karoshi ho capito cosa intendi, infatti non è sbagliata.suona solo un po' strana perchè la frase dopo il "ma" non è seguita da nulla.

Answer (score 2):

Nel tuo esempio puoi usare tanto "precisamente" come "appunto". "Appunto" si userebbe più comunemente, direi.

> In Spagna ci sono state molte proteste ..., ma questa legge cerca **[precisamente | proprio | appunto | per l'appunto]** di farla finita con le proteste dei movimenti sociali.

"per l'appunto" è un'espressione idiomatica con lo stesso significato, rafforzato, di "appunto".

Ancora meglio (IMO):

> ... ma questa legge è stata approvata **[proprio | precisamente | apposta | appositamente | espressamente | esattamente | appunto]** per ...

In generale però, i due termini non sempre sono equivalenti.

> "Quindi vuoi dire che lo faresti?" "Precisamente". (non "appunto")
>
> Mio fratello è calciatore. (Più) precisamente, un centrocampista. (non "appunto")
>
> Precisamente non lo so, comunque sono circa duecento metri. (non "appunto")

Ora non mi sovvengono esempi in cui "appunto" non sia sostituibile con "precisamente" (il che non vuol dire che non ce ne siano!), forse qualcosa del genere:

> Siccome gli esseri umani sono, appunto, umani, possono fare errori. (non "precisamente")

Però è un po' forzato e retorico (anche se è una costruzione che si usa con una certa frequenza).